# How to authenticate using scrapy spider with Zyte Smart Proxy Manager (former Crawlera) enabled?

Tags: python, scrapy, crawlera

I followed the [scrapy-zyte-smartproxy](https://scrapy-zyte-smartproxy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) documentation to integrate proxy usage into my spider. Now my spider can't log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this done we have to use [crawlera sessions](https://docs.zyte.com/smart-proxy-manager/sessions.html), furthermore, we need to [disable](https://support.zyte.com/support/solutions/articles/22000188409-does-zyte-smart-proxy-manager-handle-cookies-) crawlera [cookies](https://docs.zyte.com/smart-proxy-manager.html#x-crawlera-cookies). There's an old [PR](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-zyte-smartproxy/pull/85) but it's still not merged and doesn't work. You need to create your [own scrapy middleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#writing-your-own-spider-middleware) in `your_project/middleware.py` file to attache crawlera headers for each  spider request.

```
from scrapy import Request


class ZyteSmartProxySessionMiddleware(object):
    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        def _set_session(request_or_item):
            if not isinstance(request_or_item, Request):
                return request_or_item

            request = request_or_item
            header = b'X-Crawlera-Session'
            session = response.headers.get(header)
            error = response.headers.get(b'X-Crawlera-Error')
            session_is_bad = error == b'bad_session_id'

            if session is not None and not session_is_bad:
                request.headers[header] = session
                request.headers['X-Crawlera-Cookies'] = 'disable'

            return request

        return (_set_session(request_or_item)
                for request_or_item in result or ())
```

Enable this middleware in your `settings.py` file.

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'your_project.middlewares.ZyteSmartProxySessionMiddleware': True,
}
```

To start the session attach `X-Crawlera-Session: create` header to the login request inside your scrapy spider.

```
def parse(self, response):
    auth_data = {'username': self.user, 'password': self.password}
    request = FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata=auth_data,
                                        callback=self.redirect_to_select)
    request.headers.setdefault('X-Crawlera-Session', 'create')
    return request
```

Note that according to the documentation the spider will be slowed down after that.

> There is a default delay of 12 seconds between each request using the same IP. These delays can differ for more popular domains.